# how to mingw64 cross compiling with flex and bison?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bison, flex-lexer

I have installed mingw64 on my ubuntu 14 trusty with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw64
```

Now I figured out there is no flex or bison linked to it?

I have downloaded this flex: https://github.com/westes/flex.git

and this bison: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/bison-3.0.4.tar.xz

can somebody tell me how to link them properly to my compiler?

Comment: Flex and bison aren't "linked to" the compiler, they just happen to output C code. And they are architecture independent anyway.

Comment: but it finds FlexLexer.h with my standard compiler and with mingw64 not?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to cross-compile a mingw64 executable for a project which uses flex and bison, just use the flex and bison on you ubuntu box. What you need to cross-compile are the files generated by the flex and bison tools, but those files are not dependent on your architecture.

Comment: my problem is that, I want to make a piece of software with bison  3.0.4, flex and wxwidgets and of course c++11. 

This software should work on windows. I have started on linux to programm. If I tried to comile it with mingw on windows it does not work because there is only bison 2.4 and I do not want to go back because my grammer has around 900 lines of code. I am trying to do it now from linux. but if i find a way to get bison on windows to work or the project runs at least on wine on linux it is fine...

Comment: @rici  how to install bison 3.0.4 on windows? I mean if I try to compile it with my mingw compiler many many errors are occurring.

Comment: just downloaded and added to my windows path environment. now it works find. without compiling...